# Adding transition to delayed dynamic elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a 'slide in to the left' animation to the class `.bot-dialog`. This class is dynamically generated and my setTimeout function does not seem to be doing justice.

One of the issues I noticed was that it doesn't work ONLY when the typing indicator is active. Here is my code:

**Generate my bot dialog**

```
    $("#conversation").html(
        "<div class='bot-log'>" +
        "<span class='bot'>Chatbot: </span>" +
        "<span class='current_msg bot-dialog dialog' style='left:-40px; position:relative;'>TEST" +
        "</span> </div>"
    )

var $to = $(".bot-dialog");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $to.css("left", 200 + "px");
    }, 0);

    $(".current_msg").hide();
    //Add and remove typing indicator when firing typing function
    $(".bot-log:last-child").append(
      '<div class="typing-indicator"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>'
    );
    $(".typing-indicator").delay(800).fadeOut(function() {
      $(".typing-indicator").remove();
    });

    $(".current_msg").delay(1200).fadeIn(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("current_msg");
      if (typeof callback == "function") callback();
    });
```

**CSS for dialog/transition**

```
.bot-dialog{
  transition:5s all ease;
}
```

Here is a **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpdx2a0x/1/)** showing the issue.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what do you mean by **it doesn't work ONLY when the typing indicator is active** ?

Comment: and why are you using the timeout function?

Comment: @madalinivascu **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpdx2a0x/2/)** is a fiddle version with the indicator removed. Used the timeout because I was trying wait the 1200ms to activate the transition, but that still just flashes the div on screen.

Comment: so you want to animate the left position of the bot-dialog div?

Comment: is this what i got [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/Lpdx2a0x/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, you're hiding it, which sets it to `display: none` which affects the css transition. Just use opacity instead.

I've changed the transition from `all` to `left` so that the test appears instantly, if you want a smooth opacity, change it back to `all`

https://jsfiddle.net/Lpdx2a0x/4/

Comment: This worked for me, thanks for the help. I originally was using display none so the indicator appeared to the right, I'll just have to fiddle with some css but this is perfect!

Comment: I believe when you `display: none` it, add the transition and then `display: block` it (or whatever visibility) it'll skip the animation and go straight to the final destination.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the settimeout from `0` value greater than `0` like for example I have used `1` millisecond.

Change:

```
var $to = $(".bot-dialog");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $to.css("left", 200 + "px");
    }, 0);
```

To:

```
var $to = $(".bot-dialog");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $to.css("left", 200 + "px");
    }, 1);
```

And now it works fine.

**EDIT :** I am not sure exactly what animation you are looking for but when I remove  `$(".current_msg").hide();` and increase the delay it works as per you want.

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpdx2a0x/5/)

Comment: I've tried this, it still only flashes the div on screen at `left:200px;`